# bash script to verify that brew cask is installed

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

I am writing a script to setup a mac development environment, however I am running into an issue on some peoples macs where cask does not install. Is there a way I can verify if cask has been installed in bash?

Ideally I am looking for something like:

```
if caskIsInstalled then
     # do stuff...
fi
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7522866) help?

Comment: @ArthurHammer A bit, but it did not take me far enough.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up asking [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089486/verify-via-bash-that-a-homebrew-extenshion-cask-is-installed), where I was able to come up with this.

```
if ! brew info cask &>/dev/null; then
  echo "Failed to install Cask (Homebrew Extension)"
  exit 1
fi
```